# ROS2 Foxy slam_toolbox crashes trying to load libconsole_bridge.so.1.0

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OS:
Ubuntu 20.04

ROS2 Installation:
Ros2 Foxy through ros-foxy-desktop

Problem:

Im trying to test slam_toolbox through its binary install(sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-slam-toolbox) with my RPLidar A1, but if I try to execute the launch file `online_async_launch.py` through `ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py`
, it crashes with the error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libconsole_bridge.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[ERROR] [async_slam_toolbox_node-1]: process has died [pid 24195, exit code 127, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/slam_toolbox/async_slam_toolbox_node --ros-args -r __node:=slam_toolbox --params-file /opt/ros/foxy/share/slam_toolbox/config/mapper_params_online_async.yaml --params-file /tmp/launch_params_nr3o0zlj'].
```

apt-get says `"Unable to locate package libconsole_bridge.so.1.0"`, it seems to be apart of the ros console_bridge package, but `sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-console-bridge` is also unable to locate the package.

Is there a place where I can install this from source? Or did I install something wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360100/ros2-foxy-slam_toolbox-crashes-trying-to-load-libconsole_bridge.so.1.0/) by [rydb](https://answers.ros.org/users/53251/rydb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2020-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I installed the binaries to make sure they're not busted (*cough* maybe I should have been doing that for a while instead of only building source *cough*). Things look good on my end, I just did an apt install of slam toolbox from binaries, sourced my `/opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash` in a clean terminal and I don't get a crash.

`ros-foxy-console-bridge` you are right isn't a package, but `ros-foxy-console-bridge-vendor` is. That's what's getting your right vendor for your OS. Try installing that and potentially doing an `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to get updates in case your local lists are old.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1